# Can I just simply exchange the eyepiece in a microscope?

Tags: microscopy

I hope it's the right place to ask about microscopy. So my question is what parameters do I have to take into account when buying a new eyepiece for my microscope? Currently I own an Aomekie XSP-42 with a WF16X eyepiece and I would like to upgrade it with a WF25X eyepiece. However when I was searching for one I couldn't help but notice that only the magnification and the mounting size are indicated. What about other parameters (eg. focal distance)? Are they standardized or they just simply don't matter?

Comment: Did you try to contact the manufacturer?

Comment: No, not yet. So it is product dependent if its possible or not?